# keep SSH-port-forwarding connection alive

Tags: ssh, port-forwarding

I am doing a permanent port forwarding via SSH. It is basically

```
while true; do
        ssh <somewhere> \
                -R <dst-port>:localhost:<src-port> \
                -N -n -o ExitOnForwardFailure=yes
        sleep 10
done
```

However, that is not very reliable. Sometimes, the port is not forwarded at all (I'm not sure if the connection is correctly alive but I can see the process on the client and it is running already for several hours), sometimes the connection is surely not alive anymore (because the network interface is down) but it takes very long (sometimes up to 30-60 minutes) to timeout.

How can I make that more reliable? I want to have a timeout of maybe a minute.

---

I just found [this very related/similar question](https://superuser.com/questions/111005/stable-reverse-port-forwarding-in-ssh-and-stale-sessions). However, the first answer indicates that `ExitOnForwardFailure` should solve it but I already have that and it does not (I can see right now the running `ssh` process with this option but the port is not forwarded).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I put these in the SSH client `config` file:

```
ServerAliveInterval = 60
ServerAliveCountMax = 3
```

Alternatively, these options can be passed on the `ssh` command line via `-o`.

Some clients may not have this configuration control, such as the various meager clients for mobile devices. In that case, it is still possible to configure it globally on the each server being connected to, which of course requires privileges on the server machine. The OpenSSHD implementation doesn't seem to have a way for users to customize server parameters (no `~/.ssh/sshd_config` file is read where selected parameters could be customized from the server side).

Comment: That seems to work. I'm really surprised because I am connected to my server 24/7 for a month with plain ssh ... but when doing a reverse port forwarding, it dies pretty quickly if I don't use the "keep alive" feature.

Comment: @AlexisWilke The flipside is that keep-alive features can unnecessarily **kill** an idle connection, if there is a network outage, when otherwise that connection could have survived the outage.

Answer (score 3):

I use autossh like this on my work machine to setup for remote web development:

```
autossh -M0 -N -R \*:8080:localhost:80 -R \*:5051:localhost:22 home
```

autossh is a program that keeps restarting ssh if it crashes or stops for any reason other than "kill -9". The above command sets up two tunnels: one for forwarding port 80 on my work machine to 8080 on my home machine, the other tunnels the ssh server on my work machine to my home machine. The * in front of the port makes this work with any hostname, not just localhost. You might need to set "GatewayPorts yes" on your sshd_config for that to work though. I have hosts in ~/.ssh/config and /etc/hosts on my home machine to make this even more transparent. For other systems it's necessary to use ProxyCommand (http://sshmenu.sourceforge.net/articles/transparent-mulithop.html), but I don't have the host I use this command with powered on at the moment to grab it.

~/.ssh/config:

```
Host work
    hostname localhost
    port 5051
```

Then it's just

```
autossh -M0 -t home 'ssh work'
```

from any host to connect.

Comment: I read already about `autossh` before. However, I still have exactly the same problems as before. The connection still dies but `autossh` doesn't recognize it.

Answer (score 1):

This version sends frequently some data to the server. If the connection has died, the pipe should break sooner or later.

```
while true; do
        { while true; do echo echo ping; sleep 10; done } | \
        ssh <somewhere> \
                -R <something> \
                -o ExitOnForwardFailure=yes \
                >/dev/null
        sleep 10
done
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try changing your SSH command to:

```
ssh SOMEWHERE -R DSTPORT:localhost:SRCPORT -n -o ExitOnForwardFailure=yes \
    "while true; do echo ping; sleep 10; done" >/dev/null
```

This causes a small amount of data to be sent over the TCP connection every 10 seconds (feel free to change that period).  That may be sufficient to keep the connection alive.

Comment: Have you actually tried that? I was thinking about some similar hack, though I couldn't really believe that there would be no timeout otherwise, so I haven't even tried yet.

Comment: Yes, I've used that trick to positive effect.

Comment: I tried it now. It doesn't work, the connection still dies silently and it doesn't recognize it.

Comment: Then something other than a TCP timeout is causing the connection to fail.  If you SSH into the machine normally, and run that `while` loop from the shell prompt, will it still disconnect?  If so, you have a network problem.

Comment: How should the client now if the server is not sending anything anymore that the connection has died? I have now made a slightly different variant where the client is constantly sending something (and the SSH protocol requires to get some form of ack), so if that fails at some point, the client knows that the connection has died. See my own answer.

Comment: You answer simply changes the direction the keep-alive data is flowing.  That shouldn't matter, since TCP has to ACK that back, thus sending data in _both_ directions anyway.  But if it works, it works.

Comment: Of course it matters. If the client is not getting any data, how should it know that this is wrong? It can only timeout if it is waiting for some data but in your code, there is nothing which checks if it really is getting the data.

Comment: TCP "checks if it really is getting the data", regardless of whether user-space code is "waiting for some data".  If the ACKs are not received by the sender, TCP will eventually tear down the connection.  When you send data from the client to the server, data is also sent from the server back to the client (the TCP ACKs).  Switch the words "client" and "server" in that sentence, and it's still true.  If the network connection is not moving data in one direction or the other (and it doesn't matter which), TCP will eventually kill the connection.

Comment: It does matter. TCP will kill the connection on the side where it expects the acks but where it does not get any. In your example, that is only the server side and the connection will not die on the client side, so your code (the client side) will still hang in `ssh`. I actually tested it and can confirm that. It will never die on the client side (but of course it will on the server side).

Comment: There is no reason to create ugly hacks like that when ssh has a built in ping feature itself: ServerAliveInterval. See @kaz answer

Answer (score 0):

As quoted previously by Kaz, the connection does not seem to require any explicit traffic to keep alive. Something like:

```
ssh you@there 'read ANYTHING' < $PIPE
```

just works. $PIPE is a named pipe you'll write to when you're done.

Well, let's be explicit - the $PIPE is more complex than 'read ANYTHING' and is worth a verbose example. Here is the code I use to rdesktop a machine in a network I cannot access directly:

```
p_user=myself
p_bridge=me@there
p_host=192.168.xxx.yyy
p_port=9999

p_size=100%      # or: p_size=1280x1024
p_trace=stderr   # or: p_trace=null

s_trace() {  echo "$*" > /dev/$p_trace; }

PIPE=$TEMP/${0##*/}.$$
mkfifo $PIPE.0
mkfifo $PIPE.1

trap 'rm $PIPE.0 $PIPE.1' 0

# ----------------------------------------------------
ssh $p_bridge \
    -L $p_port:$p_host:3389 \
    'read CONNECT; date; read QUIT' \
  < $PIPE.1 \
  > $PIPE.0 \
  & 
# ----------------------------------------------------

# note: "type -p" is somehow required with xinit
# note: "-p -" reads password from stdin
DESKCMD="$(type -p rdesktop) -P -z -u $p_user -p - -g $p_size localhost:$p_port"

{
  echo connect >&3; read CONNECT <&4; s_trace "CONNECTED: $CONNECT"
  $DESKCMD -f    # or: xinit $DESKCMD -- :1
  echo quit >&3
} \
  3> $PIPE.1 \
  4< $PIPE.0

wait
```